# Understanding the MySQL Query Optimizer

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

We use two MySQL servers with the same setup and master-master replication. They are located behind a loadbalancer and get almost the same traffic, statements etc.

On server1, there are some cron jobs running additionally, which is the only difference.

However, we've seen that the query optimizer in some cases behaves different with the same query on both servers.
In those cases we have to use FORCE_INDEX to get the best results on both servers.

The main questions are:

- Is there any metadata that is stored somewhere on the server that is used by the Query Optimizer?
- If we have to backup and restore a database (with XtraBackup), will the query optimizer behave in the same way or is it built from scratch?

Thanks for any reply
Joachim

Comment: An official guide: http://www.unofficialmysqlguide.com/ and an official guide: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer.html

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: (That "unofficial" guide was written by a person very knowledgeable about MySQL.)  Here is another, more limited, guide:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer bases its actions partially on "statistics".  Those statistics come from explicit `ANALYZE TABLE` or from certain changes to the table, such as "adding more than 10% to the table".

There is nothing to sync the stats between the two Masters, so they can drift apart.  Even running `ANALYZE TABLE` on both will not necessarily bring them in sync.  This is because of the "random probes" that are made into the table to concoct the stats.

`FORCE INDEX` is risky because "what helps today may hurt tomorrow".

Probably this is what is happening:  You have a query that is on the borderline between picking one query plan and another.  The Optimizer's analysis says they are about equivalent, but (for various reasons) they are not.  This could lead to one server doing one thing (fast query plan) and the other doing something else (poor query plan).

There is no 'reliable' and 'consistent' way to solve your problem.

Let's try to tackle it a different way.  Provide the query, the `EXPLAIN`, and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  There *may* be a better index and/or a reformulation of the query that avoids the problem completely, and possibly runs faster than either of your current query plans.